# How to convert an array to string efficiently in PySpark / Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `df` with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

in which one of the columns, `col2` is an array `[1#b, 2#b, 3#c]`. I want to convert this to the string format `1#b,2#b,3#c`.

I am currently doing this through the following snippet

```
df2 = (df1.select("*", explode(col2)).drop('col2'))
df2.groupBy("col1").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list('col')).alias("col2"))
```

While this gets the job done, it is taking time and also seems inefficient.

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 22):

You can call `concat_ws` directly on a column, like this:

```
df1.withColumn('col2', concat_ws(',', 'col2'))
```